# How to join two tables based on their owner_id?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: owners_table and items_table.

Owners_table:

```
OwnerID,Name(this is the owner's name),Email
```

Items_table:

```
ItemID, OwnerID,Name(this is the item name),Location
```

I need to display in the datagridview the `Itemid,ownerid,name(of owner),name(of item), location.`
I need some help in the query :) i want to join the table using the ownerid that will connect both tables. Thank you!

Comment: Hint:  `SELECT`, `JOIN`.

Comment: `SELECT Items.itemid, Owners.ownerid, Owners.name, Items.name, Items.location FROM Owners_table AS Owners, Items_table AS Items WHERE Owners.ownerId = Items.ownerId`

Answer (score 0):

Use this query with alias for name columns :

```
select
    O.OwnerID,
    I.Itemid,
    I.Name as ItemName,
    O.Name as OwnerName,
    I.Location
from
    Owners_table O
    inner join Items_table I on
        O.OwnerID = I.OwnerID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
select I.Itemid, I.ownerid, I.name as ItemName, O.name as OwnerName, I.location from
Items_table I join Owners_table O on I.ownerid = O.ownerid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT E.ItemID, C.OwnerID, C.Name as Owner, E.Name as Item, E.Location
From C.Owners_table join E.Items_table 
ON C.OwnerID = E.OwnerID
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change joined column name based on your table.

```
SELECT Items.itemid, Owners.ownerid, Owners.name, Items.name FROM Owners_table Owners join  Items_table Items on Items.OwnerId=Owners.id
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT dbo.Owners_table.OwnerID, dbo.Items_table.ItemID, dbo.Items_table.Name AS ITEM_NAME, dbo.Owners_table.Name AS Owner_name, dbo.Items_table.Location
FROM    dbo.Items_table INNER JOIN
  dbo.Owners_table ON dbo.Items_table.OwnerID = dbo.Owners_table.OwnerID